# VB If statement AND/OR

Tags: vb.net

If the user input an "A" or "a" .. the output is Apple. That would also work in letters "B" "C" and so fort... Where/How should I put And/Or operator?

```
Private Sub txtchange_Change()

If txtchange.Text = "A" Then
    lbloutput.Caption = "Apple"

ElseIf txtchange.Text = "B" Then
    lbloutput.Caption = "Banana"

ElseIf txtchange.Text = "C" Then
    lbloutput.Caption = "Cat"

ElseIf txtchange.Text = "D" Then
    lbloutput.Caption = "Dog"

Else
    lbloutput.Caption = "Not Found"

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you need to. Why do you think you do?

Comment: We don't know what you're trying to accomplish, which makes it very hard to know where you should use `And` or `Or`.

Comment: If, instead, you'd asked "How can I improve this code", I'd have pointed you towards [`Select...Case`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y(v=vs.110).aspx), but as it is, I agree with others that the question's very unclear.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do, because no one can read your mind and determine why you think you need to interject `AND/OR` logic into this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for simple .. use SELECT CASE

```
Private Sub txtchange_Change()

Select case Ucase(txtchange.Text)
case "A" : lbloutput.Caption = "Apple"
case "B" : lbloutput.Caption = "Banana"
case "C" : lbloutput.Caption = "Cat"
case "D" : lbloutput.Caption = "Dog"
case "RED" : lbloutput.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
case Else
  lbloutput.Caption = "Not Found"
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you :) I haven't encountered Select Case yet. Maybe that's why. But thank you.

Comment: @KC-Chan .. it's not about `select case` .. it's in Ucase function() .. just change yours with `if ucase(txtchange.Text) = "A"` .. `if ucase(txtchange.Text) = "B"` .. and so on ..

Answer (score 0):

If txtchange.Text = "A" Or txtchange.Text = "a" Then
    lbloutput.Caption = "Apple"

Answer (score 0):

You can have as :
If txtchange.Text = "A" OR txtchange.Text = "a" Then
    lbloutput.Caption = "Apple"